# Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1001 "The request timed out."

Tags: php, ios, apache, post, nsurlsession

Assumption: There is a bug in iOS 8.1.2 that means that none of the network code packages will work (`NSURLSession / AFNetworking`) - for any request to my `PHP` backend...all I get is:

`Error: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1001 "The request timed out." UserInfo=0x1740fae80 {NSUnderlyingError=0x1742460f0 "The request timed out.", NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=http://192.168.1.10/spiritmap/accessy/smackit/insertdata.php, NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://192.168.1.10/spiritmap/accessy/smackit/insertdata.php, NSLocalizedDescription=The request timed out.}`

Supposedly there is a workaround listed [here](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/issues/2314) and summarized below:

Add `BrowserMatch "^iOS/8\." nokeepalive` to my apache config file `httpd.conf` - I have tried:

`<IfModule setenvif_module>
BrowserMatch "^iOS/8\.2" nokeepalive
</IfModule>`

But it does not seem to work - can anyone tell me how to get this workaround to workaround (lol).

Comment: Ever find a solid fix for this? There's some stuff around but nothing concrete.

Comment: @yvanscher my problem was fixed when they updated the iOS - it ended up being a bug that apple needed to address